# What is the Shi'ite ruling of "eyebrow removing (like women)" for men?

Tags: halal-haram, shiism, men

There is a narration from the apostle of Allah (pbuh) who said:

> Every woman who makes herself like men or every man who makes himself
>   like women, is not from us. (Mizan-Al-Hekmah, Vol5, Pg18)

Or for instance there is another narration from Imam Muhammad al-Baqir (the fifth Imam of Shia Islam) (a.s.):

> لَا يَجُوزُ لِلْمَرْأَةِ أَنْ تَتَشَبَّهَ بِالرِّجَالِ لِأَنَّ رَسُولَ
>   اللَّهِ ص لَعَنَ الْمُتَشَبِّهِينَ مِنَ الرِّجَالِ بِالنِّسَاءِ وَ
>   لَعَنَ الْمُتَشَبِّهَاتِ مِنَ النِّسَاءِ بِالرِّجَالِ
>
> … because the Prophet dawned (La'n) the men who make themselves like
>   women and also women who make themselves similar to men.
>   (Bahar-Al-Anwaar, Vol 103, Pg 208).

Unfortunately, nowadays as you can see in many Islamic societies, there are many men(particularly young boys) who remove(cut) their eyebrows like ladies. As a result, commonly, their faces somewhat changes likes girls. So, I was wondering what its ruling is according to Shi'ite scholars?

Actually is it Haram or Makruh? Or even permissible?

([www.porsemanequran.com](http://www.porsemanequran.com/node/22953) (in Farsi))

Comment: Do you have the isnad?  I couldn't find anything Sahih related to the Prophet about it.

Comment: @Sayyid, As far as I know, it is relatively an authentic book (Shia view). It also consists of many narrations from both Shia and Sunni. Of course as far I can remember, there are many traditions which have mentioned regarding the obscenity of the mentioned act. (for men to make themselves like women and likewise vice versa)

Comment: or for instance there is another narration from Imam Baqer (a.s.):
لَا يَجُوزُ لِلْمَرْأَةِ أَنْ تَتَشَبَّهَ بِالرِّجَالِ لِأَنَّ رَسُولَ اللَّهِ ص لَعَنَ الْمُتَشَبِّهِينَ مِنَ الرِّجَالِ بِالنِّسَاءِ وَ لَعَنَ الْمُتَشَبِّهَاتِ مِنَ النِّسَاءِ بِالرِّجَالِ

… because the Prophet dawned (La'n) the men who make themselves like women and also women who make themselves similar to men. (Bahar-Al-Anwaar, Vol103, Pg208). So, Bahar-Al-Anwaar is an authentic source of Shia …. .anyhow, thank you dear Sayyid for paying attention to the issue above.

Comment: @Sayyid, I added another narration concerning the mentioned matter as well. It is very nice of you that reminded me... .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**According to Shia school of thought, in accordance with the view (Fatwa) of Ayatollah Khamenei (as a Marja Al-Taqlid of Shia):**

It is not permissible if:

> It is considered as the imitation or likeness of man to woman,
>
> or will be the cause of sin committing,
>
> or it is considered as the promotion of west vulgar culture.

---

**In accordance with Ayatollah Makarem Shirazi (as another  Shia Marja'al-taqlid):**

> It is not permissible for men to  make themselves like women, but it
> does not matter for a minor cutting and arranging of some parts which
> have not good apparent.

---

For further information, you can refer to the source below:

- [islamquest.net](http://islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa9429) (in Farsi)

Comment: I don't think the Prophet actually forbade women and men from doing their eyebrows.  Most of those narrations are from other people attributing it to Nabi and not actually quoting him.  Some mistake the saying of Abdullah bin Masoud as the Prophets words.

Comment: Why not @Sayyid. Anyway there are many different hadiths which are considered as authentic traditions from the view of some sects and vice versa. Of course I assume u agree that some shapes of eyebrow removing could be considered as the imitation or likeness of man to woman, which won't be acceptable from Islam. Thank you for noticing it. Good luck.

Comment: -1, Western culture is not vulgar.

Answer (score -1):

A person must have diagnosis from psychologist that they are transgender and therefore it is a medical condition the person suffers and deserve surgery to fix then. If a boy has surgery to come a girl, will it still be wrong for them to beautify the face, when Allah says the face is allowed for adorement.

Answer (score -2):

I think it is prohibited for both men and women because of **Qur'an 4:119** - we should not change what Allah made.

Comment: To some extent, I agree you, but I assume it won't be prohibited for women in case non-Mahram do not see her. (by wearing veil...), otherwise it would be prohibited if it is considered as makeup (that non-Mahram see...). Good luck.